# How to split the Group header across two pages

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a Group header which is the first thing displaying when details are displaying. My question is 
"When my details are splitting across two pages, I want to display the same headed again on the second page ". Sometime when details are displaying in one page then it is fine.

### Page1

### Customer id :- 12345

- Detail-1
- Detail-2

---

### Page2

- Details-3

---

I want in below format. Please help me.

### Page1

### Customer id :-12345

- Detail-1
- Detail-2

---

### Page2

### Customer id:-12345

- Details-3

Answer (score 0):

Go to Group Expart, click on 'options' button. Select the 'options' tab and check 'Repeat group header on each page

Comment: Thanks a lot Pragnesh. I got it.